# django authentication with hashed password or convert it to plain

Tags: python, django, authentication

Lets say I have email of user

```
user = User.objects.get(email="anyone@anymail.com")
```

Now I want to login this user like:

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=user.password)
```

Authenticate do not take hashed password. But here i can only get hashed password. How can I login this user lets say to change its password

Thank you

Comment: are you having trouble logging in or its just password you are stuck at??

Comment: Why do you need to log a user in before you change the password?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787650/manually-logging-in-a-user-without-password with an excellent answer by Daniel

Comment: trouble loggin in with that

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that answer is still valid. But my point above remains: why do you need to log the user in at all?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to log in a user to change the password. You can use the Django's [`set_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords) helper function to change the password.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.get(email="anyone@anymail.com")
user.set_password('new_password')
user.save() # call save explicitly
```

As per the docs,

> set_password(raw_password)
>   Sets the user’s password to the given raw
>   string, taking care of the password hashing. Doesn’t save the User
>   object.