# Password-less website authentification / login

Tags: authentication, language-agnostic, password-less

Many websites have a password-less authentification system, i.e. you can signup / login / logout only with an email, and no password is ever required.

**How would one implement such a system?** (framework and language-agnostic)

Note: I've already read:

- [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication),
- [Password-less authentication in web apps - How safe it is?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86328/password-less-authentication-in-web-apps-how-safe-it-is)
   and a few other security.SE posts
- and [searched for SO posts about](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=without%20password%20authentification) how to actually implement a [[password-less]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/password-less) login system, but without much success ; I haven't found a canonical question on SO about implementation of a password-less auth
- [Manually logging in a user without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787650/manually-logging-in-a-user-without-password) is linked but not the same thing: there the idea is login immediately *after* a successful account creation, but not necessarily a 100% password-less authentification system.

Comment: (Note: as I searched for a long time for this, here is a summary that I post with SO's "Answer your own question - Q&A-style" feature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I searched for a long time for this, here is a summary that I post with SO's "Answer your own question - Q&A-style"  feature. I'll update it as often as I can to improve it.

### Password-less authentification method #1: *"Click on the link in the email we just sent you to login"*

Sign-up:

- client fills signup form
- client AJAX POST http://example.com/_signup `{email: 'test@test.com', data: 'data'}`
- server checks if user already exists
- client message: *"Success: an email has been sent"* or *"Fail: already exists"*
- server creates DB record for user
- server generates a random session ID + sends email with link: http://example.com/?sessid=f65a5bc45

Log-in:

- client fills login form
- client AJAX POST http://example.com/_login `{email: 'test@test.com'}`
- client message: *"An email has been sent if the account exists"*
- server checks if the email is in the database
- server generates a random session ID + sends email with link: http://example.com/?sessid=f65a5bc45

Open link:

- client opens the link http://example.com/?sessid=f65a5bc45
- client: `document.cookie = "sessid=f65a5bc45; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT"` (or do this server side, e.g. with PHP)
- client: `?sessid` query string removed, navigate to `/`

Open `/`:

- client: AJAX POST example.com/_load `{sessid: getCookieValue('sessid')}`
- server checks if valid sessid. if so, sends user data to client
- client `xhr.onreadystatechange`: fills page with user data

---

## Password-less authentification method #2: *"Enter the code in the email we just sent you to login, e.g. 123 456"*

Sign-up:

- client fills signup form
- client AJAX POST http://example.com/_signup `{email: 'test@test.com', data: 'data'}`
- client message *"An email has been sent, please enter your code here:"* or *"Fail: already exists"*
- server creates DB record for user
- idem next paragraph starting at (*)

Log-in:

- client fills login form
- client AJAX POST http://example.com/_login `{email: 'test@test.com'}`
- client message *"An email has been sent if the account exists, please enter your code here:"*
- server checks if email in database
- (*) server generates random number + sends email: *"Here is your code: 123 456"*
- client fills code form
- client AJAX POST http://example.com/_login `{email: 'test@test.com', code: '123456'}`
- server checks if valid code. if so, server generates a random session ID, and sends to client
- client: `document.cookie = "sessid=f65a5bc45; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT"` (or do this server side with PHP)
- client: navigate to `/`

Open `/`:

- client AJAX POST http://example.com/_load `{sessid: getCookieValue('sessid')}`
- server checks if valid sessid. if so, sends user data to client
- client `xhr.onreadystatechange`: fills page with user data